# Running exe in QtCreator has different working directory than outside QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, working-directory

when I compile and run an application inside QtCreator, the current working directory is the build directory, i.e. the folder named "build-MyProject-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_32bit" in my case, but this isn't the directory the exe resides in. The exe can be found in the debug or release subdirectory, which is the "current working directory" when I run the exe outside of QtCreator. How can I make QtCreator use this path as current working directory as well? I already tried to change the directory under "Projects" in my Run settings, but it looks like I can't use different directories for the debug and release builds.

edit: Calling this a duplicate is a bit far fetched in my opinion, because the "duplicate" refers to creating a DB, while mine refers to weird behavior from QtCreator. The question I actually asked was how to change QtCreator's properties, because it's weird to call my exe from a parent folder. Visual Studio never did that to me. The lesson (don't use the current working directory unless you explicitly set it) may be the same, but the questions were completely different, so I had no way of finding a solution to my problem by searching stackoverflow instead of asking.

Comment: Can you not work around this another way? In a general sense, you as a developer have no control over what the user actually calling your program has as current working directory. It is rather inflexible to assume things about your CWD in your code...

Comment: I see. Well, I want to access some files relative to my exe, if I can't be sure that that's always the CWD. Should I go with Kevin's answer below then?

Comment: see my answer for a robust solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your program to always use the location of executable as its working directory, then you can just do that from inside the application code

```
QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not the exact thing I wanted, but it works and I can live with having to put in one extra line of code. If nobody finds a way for me to change QtCreator's properties in a way to solve my problem, then I will mark this as an answer. I don't know who downvoted it, but I upvoted it now to even it out.

Comment: @Alex You approach the problem the wrong way: you should first ask yourself "Is my assumption that working directory is to be depended on correct?" The answer is: No. You can't assume anything of it upon startup. If you need it to be something in particular, you have to explicitly set it. Perhaps you should not be using relative paths in your application, instead using absolute paths that include the `applicationDirPath()`.

Comment: @Kuba Ober: Your comment doesn't explain why I shouldn't use Kevin's solution and just set the CWD to a meaningful value. Is it possible for other applications to screw with that? Or am I potentially disturbing an application calling mine from a different directory? Can the CWD change at any random point in time or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find files relative to your executable, it is not a good idea to rely on the Current Working Directory, which is determined by where your program is called from, not where the executable file lives.

To find the location of your executable, use [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath). Note that this is still a bit flaky with respect to cross-platform portability, as e.g. Unix or MacOS will tend to put files related to your program in radically different locations than on a Windows PC by convention.

If I call your program like this:

```
some/subdir/yourprogram
```

the current working directory will not be `some/subdir`, and your logic will fail.

Comment: I see, that's good to know. Then I shall use Kevin's approach. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Congrats on choosing the broken approach!

Answer (score -1):

As the oposite workAround proposed by Kevin Krammer, you can change the working directory outside Qt Creator :

Admitting this configuration : 
C:\buildDir\debug
C:\buildDir\release

Make a batch in `C:\buildDir\launch.bat` (for exemple) which launches your executable : `release\yourexe.exe`

This batch can be use sooner or later to specify some useful environment variables or log redirections.

(PS : I suppose you are under Windows regarding your compiler, but this works similarly on linux)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I don't wish to create a batch-file just to handle relative paths for my exe. The downvote wasn't me.